# Runing Android project inside android project

Tags: java, android

I am totally new to Android studio and Java. I am building project. I have made two main activities with buttons. In second activity I have 14 buttons. My goal is to click one of the buttons, which will start new activity with big image which I can pinch zoom. I found this [subsampling-scale-image-view](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view)

How can I apply this custom imageview with my existing project? Can someone please give me step by step solution? I have tried to import it as module, but I can not run new activity for button as it is described in setup. I am maybe doing something wrong, but I can not figure out how to do it. I spent hours on it.

Comment: Read it's document. Add that as a library in your app's gradle file

Comment: following is the right answer of your question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio

Comment: Thank you, it was more simple than I thought. I was just doing too much things and messed it up everytime.